# kdevelop intellisense

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, intellisense, kdevelop

How can I enable the intellisence in KDevelop using C++ and QT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to provide us with information on what language you're talking about? KDevelop is multi-language IDE. 
AFAIK IntelliSense availability is depending on plugins enabled.

--

**edited** 
ok, now when you specified the language ... have a look here :)
http://www.kdevelop.org/mediawiki/index.php/FAQ#How_can_I_enable_code_completion.3F

I believe your problem was about the naming - IntelliSense is registered by Microsoft thus most open-source projects tend to name that feature CodeCompletion :)

Comment: right, thnx for the info, I've changed the question a little bit

Comment: you've changed the question, so did I with the answer ;) ;)

Answer (score 1):

in KDevelop 4 you don't need to enable anything. It should work out-of-the-box for C++ projects. Just make sure the include paths are set up properly, but for CMake projects this is supposed to work automagically.